# Transferring Django project from Windows to Mac

Tags: windows, django, macos

I have a very simple Django project working on my Windows machine. When I try zipping the project root and unzipping the contents on my Mac I get runtime errors on all the pages. Are there any known differences between how Django is configured/called on Windows vs. Mac, perhaps in `settings.py`? I can't seem to figure it out. `django.get_version()` returns `'1.3'` on both machines.

Comment: Sorry, psychic ray not working... presumably those "runtime errors" come with actual *error messages*, which you might like to post so we can help you.

Comment: The error logs are long and, from what I can tell, redundant. It says it can't find a 500.html template, which I have, and which works on my Windows machine.
http://pastebin.com/5mjZkyNs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One annoyance I had with this was the file paths in settings.py since in osx your directories look like '/path/to/directory'.

Comment: You mean the ones that on Windows are written like `'path.to.directory'`? On windows `settings.py` has both syntaxes, with / slashes and . periods for different variables.

Comment: yeah. i never used the period notation which is why i had problems. also, you mention you're having template errors, so check to make sure everything is on your python path

Comment: You turned out to be going in the right direction with that, it was the `TEMPLATE_DIRS`, which are absolutes, that were incorrect on my new system. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, writing it down to perhaps help someone else with the same problem:

It turned out to be a stupid oversight of my `TEMPLATE_DIRS`, I have a differently-spelled username on my new machine. These seem to be the only absolute path involved in Django. Same syntax as before:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
'/Users/artur/Projects/pollsite',
'/Users/artur/Projects/pollsite/polls_templates'
)
```

I also updated to [Python 2.7](http://www.python.org/download/) from the built-in 2.6 that Apple ships their computers with (although Django docs say 2.4+ will work) After doing those two things my project works, so it looks like Django translates cross-platform well.